# Parsing, splitting and rverse the content of a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the content of a file:

```
alpha-32: pt2, pb,
beta-45:  pc
teta-52:  pt2, pk,
gama-86d: pt3, pc,
```

- in the first column, the elements/strings are unique per line
- in the second column the string are not unique

I want to get a reverse correspondence, using a dictionary and arrays:

```
{
pt2: [alpha-32, teta-52]
pb: [alpha-32]
pc: [beta-45, gama-86d]
pt3: [ gama-86d]
}
```

I tried:

```
content = file_content.split(\n)
for l in content:

 s2_column = {}
 a = l.split(':')[0]
 b = l.split(':')[1][:-1]

 for el in b:
   s2_column[el] = [a]
```

The first issues, to split b, is that I have an "'", at the end, and no element. 
Maybe there is a shorter/simple method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:                        #Iterate each line
        value, keys = line.strip().split(":")   #split by ":"
        for key in keys.strip(",").split(","):   #split by ","
            result.setdefault(key.strip(), []).append(value)   #Create result
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'pb': ['alpha-32'],
 'pc': ['beta-45', 'gama-86d'],
 'pk': ['teta-52'],
 'pt2': ['alpha-32', 'teta-52'],
 'pt3': ['gama-86d']}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, make use of `string.strip(chars)` to remove all leading and trailing unwanted chars. This way you can remove the trailing commas, and get rid of the unwanted empty strings

You can find below a snippet that does the job.

```py
data="""alpha-32: pt2, pb,
beta-45:  pc
teta-52:  pt2, pk,
gama-86d: pt3, pc,"""

# build a dictionary matching id with corresponding tags
parsed_data = dict()
for line in data.splitlines():
    hid, tags_str = line.split(":")
    tags = tags_str.strip(' ,').split(',')
    parsed_data[hid] = [t.strip() for t in tags]

print(parsed_data)
# {'alpha-32': ['pt2', 'pb'], 'beta-45': ['pc'], 'teta-52': ['pt2', ' pk'], 'gama-86d': ['pt3', ' pc']}

# reverse the dictionary
tags_lookup = dict()
for hid, tags in parsed_data.items():
    for tag in tags:
        tags_lookup.setdefault(tag, []).append(hid)

print(tags_lookup)
# {'pt2': ['alpha-32', 'teta-52'], 'pb': ['alpha-32'], 'pc': ['beta-45'], 'pk': ['teta-52'], 'pt3': ['gama-86d'], 'pc': ['gama-86d']}
```